# MXNET reshape calling ctypes

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, ctypes, mxnet

Here trying to learn MXNET with “The Straight Dope”. On Linear Algebra - Tensors, I get ctypes error when running,

```
X = nd.arange(24).reshape((2, 3, 4))
```

The error is,

```
C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\mxnet\ndarray\ndarray.pyc in reshape(self, *shape, **kwargs)
   1060                                            c_array(ctypes.c_int64, shape),
   1061                                            reverse,
-> 1062                                            ctypes.byref(handle)))
   1063         return NDArray(handle=handle, writable=self.writable)
   1064

WindowsError: exception: access violation writing 0x00007FFB00000000
```

Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discussed the solution here: https://discuss.mxnet.io/t/reshape-error-calling-ctypes/1245/3

What helped is to downgrade to mxnet 1.2.0 and upgraded to Python 2.7.15.